# Informix 5.10 setup or a compatible version

Tags: informix

We're looking for a setup of Informix 5.10 database.
We need to create a connector to an existing (and old) database on a client's production environment but we haven't found a link to download the appropriate version to setup our development environment.
We have done some tests with a newer version but there are many differences with the 5.10 that make more difficult (or impossible) to work on development time.

Any help on this?

thanks in advance!!

Comment: You need to be asking a question?  This is not a freelancer job site Pepe.   If you have been having problems, you need to explain what you did, how you did it, and all the error information.

Comment: OnLine 5.10 has not been available during the current millennium.  OnLine 5.20 is available on a few platforms; it has not been released in the current decade, AFAIK, so it only runs on archaic platforms.  If I could find a version to work with, I'd be happy; it isn't trivial to find.  It almost certainly isn't available except by contacting IBM sales channels or perhaps IBM (or HCL) Tech Support, and you'll likely need patience (a lot of patience) to persuade people that you're not talking about fictitious products.  Note that ESQL/C 5.20 is a separate product from OnLine 5.20.

Comment: One advantage of 5.20 over 5.10 is that 5.20 includes the networking support in the base version.  Back when 5.00 was released (circa 1992), you had to buy I-Star and/or I-Net separately from OnLine to get network connectivity.  The configuration for 5.20 is still radically different from the ASF-connection mechanisms used with ESQL/C 6.00 and ODS 6.00 upwards, including SE 7.2x.

Comment: In case you can't read between the lines — it is beyond high time that the customer moved from the Informix 5.x family of products.  They were released more than a quarter century ago.  They've had more than twenty years of upgraded products (6.x, 7.x, 9.x, 10.x, 11.x to the current 12.x products) in which to switch to something more modern.  (Of those, only 11.70 and 12.10 are still supported.) . Don't get me wrong; OnLine 5.x was a terrific product for its original time.  I have many fond memories of it.  But they should only be memories, not daily reality.